# Winforms. Radiobuttons в FlowLayout panel

Tags: .net, winforms

Доброго дня!
Ситуация обстоит так. Имеется flowlayout panel постоянного размера с flowdirection = topdown. В него добавляется различное количество radiobutton's, содержащие по несколько строк (так чтобы текст radiobutton'a умещался по ширине). При некотором количестве кнопок появляется вертикальный скролл.

Проблема состоит в следующем: когда одна из кнопок выбрана и я передвигаю скролл, так чтобы выбранная пропадала из поля зрения, панель фокусируется на выбранной кнопке и возвращает мой скролл назад, так чтобы была видна выбранная кнопка. Таким образом просмотреть все кнопки кроме выбранной оказывается невозможным. Мне же необходимо, чтобы после выбора кнопки, было возможно пролистывать всю панель.

Подскажите путь решения проблемы. Спасибо!